Do shared libraries written in different languages use the same amount of memory?
I have a project that uses Rust as a base with the ability to extend it's functionality through shared libraries that are written in Rust, Go, and C++. The functionality I'd be adding does not use up a lot of memory, but I similarly don't want to use up more memory than I need to, while also try to keep the dev time down while achieving the goal of the extended library.
If I wrote the same code in either Rust, Go, or C++ and created a shared library for them, would the resulting library file by the same size? When imported and used by the core application, would it take up the same amount of memory regardless of what the source language was?

you wouldnt "write the same code" when it is for a different lagnauge. Hence, I wouldnt expect it to use same amount of memory. Or maybe it does ;)


If I wrote the same code in either Rust, Go, or C++

Unlikely to be possible but for the most trivial of software.

and created a shared library for them, would the resulting library file by the same size?

No.

When imported and used by the core application, would it take up the same amount of memory regardless of what the source language was?

No. The binary size, linking, and runtime components of the language would influence the space the shared library takes.

My personal expectations are that the C++ version would take the least memory, kind-of, as I believe the standard library is generally dynamically linked (at least outside windows) and can be shared between processes, although the coding style would also be a factor (copy v share v move).
Rust would probably be next, as the standard library is statically linked and it similarly has no runtime.
Go would almost certainly be last, because it also tends to use static linking and has a heavyweight runtime and has a garbage collector which generally needs double the actual memory need to do its job.
Although a confounding factor here is that both C++ and Rust have a strong tendency (linguistic and styllistic) to monomorphise, which increases the size of the final binary.

Go has a runtime, but I don't think it's heavyweight - it's certainly lightweight compared to most popular languages with runtimes (JVM, CLR, Ruby, V8 for Node, etc). The Go GC also does not "generally need double the actual memory to do its job" - I'm not sure what gave you that impression.

@Adrian a lightweight runtime is the CRT. The Go runtime includes a GC and an entire scheduler and green threading system, it's absolutely a heavy runtime. That the JVM exists doesn't make it less so.

@Adrian and 100% overhead is what GOGC=100 means: if your memory use is stable, Go has allocated 200% of your working set and waits until the new heap reaches 100% before it collects and brings the internal memory consumption back to the live heap. That collected memory is not released back, it's kept for the next growth cycle. that's literally explained by the official garbage collector guide. That is pretty much the default for "advanced" garbage collectors (as opposed to RC where total heap tends to more precisely track actual heap).

The GC would only be part of the Go runtime, which wouldn't make a difference for a shared libary developed in Go that's imported into a Rust project. I'm less concerned with the disk size of the library binary file and more with the memory usage - I was under the impression that the compiled library is optimized down to a universal format (for that OS & architecture) that there shouldn't be major differences in what language the source came from.
That's probably very difficult to compare directly since all 3 languages operate very differently from one another

@Masklinn that's true only if your steady state is exactly at the boundary of a heap growth, i.e. the worst-case scenario. It's not the general case; most applications will grow the heap until they reach steady state, and their steady state will consume some portion of that last allocated chunk.

@Hunter_AP, I would say this question is possibly the closest approximation we could pull out of thin air (what you have actually asked us to do, anyway ;)) but I'd rather urge you to look at the problem at a different angle: on todays hardware—unless maybe we're talking about hardcore embedded stuff–the amount a library's code, BSS and data segments would occupy is mostly irrelevant, and that is contrary to the amount of RSS memory that code will allocate and use when being run. And that heavily depends both on the language and algorithms/data structures and 3rd-party libraries used.

@Hunter_AP the Go runtime is not optional, a Go shared library has to embed the entire runtime, and the GC is part of the equation and will necessarily be used when the Go code you're running into executes if you're doing anything which leaves the stack. The "universal format" is machine code and the C ABI, but that's just for the communication boundary. That's why without an alternate compiler / runtime (tinygo) a wasm package created from Go is about 2MB baseline, while rust or C++ will yield something closer to 200K and can be optimised down to single digit.

@Hunter_AP incidentally the GC is one of the big issues when linking to managed languages as you need to be extremely careful when you move objects out of the shared library, shared objects might be GC'd as they're being used by the caller, which requires either only returning off-heap objects, or pinning (protecting) FFI-shared objects.

Rust has a small runtime library. It also supports dynamic linking in some platforms: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html#static-and-dynamic-c-runtimes

No. The library file would almost certainly be different because you're compiling different code in different languages with different compilers, so you're not likely to get identical binaries out of it. The memory usage for identical data structures used the same way in the three languages listed should be similar in general as they're all relatively low-level languages, but there can easily be differences between implementation details that would affect memory usage.

So for example, if my core application was written in C++ and I developed the same shared library in both Go and Rust, I should expect that the DLL/SO file I compile and import into the core program to operate differently? I suppose the library binaries are built to a certain specification, and otherwise perform differently based on what decisions the compiler makes when building the library.

@Hunter_AP not only the decisions the compiler makes, but the decisions the developer makes; you cannot write identical code in different languages because it wouldn't compile, so the developer is making some implementation decisions in porting an implementation to another language. Different code, in a different language, built by a different compiler.

Say I do make shared libraries in all 3 languages to operate as closely as possible, and develop main programs in each language to import the different shared library versions. Should I expect that a Go library imported into the other languages to use more memory than the same library written in Rust? Is the memory usage of these libraries proportional/the same as a compiled main program in that language? (IE: a Go app uses X MB RAM, and the shared library for it takes up X MB disk space, whereas a Rust app uses 2X MB RAM and 2X the disk size)

@Hunter_AP it depends on the actual code involved.
